# Awesomium: Control other app like sendmessage

Tags: vb.net, controls, sendmessage, awesomium

Today I had an idea for a program in vb.net that should add some global hotkeys to Spotify.
I tried to do this with sendmessages, but it didn't work, because Spotify uses Awesomium and so most of the controls aren't Windows-Controls which I can get with sendmessage.

Is there any other possibility to "remoteclick" a button inside the webviewhost?
Or has anyone an other idea how I could click a button in Spotify with my program?

Answer (score 0):

You can do almost anything using AutoIt. Check into that. Lots of game bots are used with it.